# Implementing Up navigation on fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have a MainActivity which contains FragmentA. When I click on FragmentA, this happens:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new PrefFragment()).addToBackStack("back").commit();
```

I have this in my manifest:

```
<activity>
<meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

and this in MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_head_sound);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new FragmentA)
                .commit();
    }
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}
```

But the Up Button navigation is always visible.

FragmentB contains this code:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id=item.getItemId();
        switch (id)
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"CLick",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);



    }
```

This code doesn't run.
I need to implement Up navigation only in FragmentB. How can I do that?

Comment: getInstance of action bar in that fragment and setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the up navigation must work only in FragmentB, whereas if FragmentA is shown the up navigation will be hidden. If so, then in Activity, remove `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` from `onCreate`.

Also you must return true when you handled menu click, and move the onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) to Activity since android.R.id.home menu click is only delivered to the Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"CLick",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true; //Notice you must returning true here

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In FragmentA

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity a) {
    super.onAttach(a);
    a.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
}
```

In FragmentB

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity a) {
    super.onAttach(a);
    a.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Ok now appear only in FragmentB but don't show toast and don't return in FragmentA when i click Up Button

Comment: @user1608228 I thought you needed to go to FragmentA if the FragmentB is shown. If the FragmentA is shown, you didn't want up navigation, or did you? Then the question is unclear to me.

Comment: Yes i need to go to FragmentA if the FragmentB is shown, now the up button is ok but when i click nothing happens

Comment: @user1608228 I see. The reason is that the Fragment doesn't have it's menu so onOptionsItemSelected is not called. Move `onOptionsItemSelected` code to `Activity`.